# How to make Java not call a external lib

Tags: java, architecture

I have a large system in Java, which basicaly consists of an user interface, the "core engine" of the application and a lot of other modules.
I am trying to create an applet that will consist only of the "core engine", without the other parts, so I need to share the same codebase to keep up with the updates.
I've done this and it works well, the problem is that there are a lot of external jars used in the other parts that I don't need, and the applet currently requires them all.

I don't call the part of the code that needs the external jar and the stack trace gives me an error when I am calling a constructor of a class, so what I am guessing is that it requires the jars as soon as this class (that I'm using the constructor) is loaded. But I've read on the internet that Java only loads classes when required, so I'm not sure what is going on here. Could anybody give me some advice about how can I make it not need these jars?

PS: I'm sure the best approach would be to refactor it, separating the functionality into clear layers, so I could tackle this more easily. The problem is that this is a very old and big codebase and doing this kind of mass-refactoring (although I would like to) is not viable right now.

Edit - adding one of the stack traces and more information:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:3000/applet/jess.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getJarFileWithoutCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadJarFileWithoutCache(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:187)
    at my.package.MyApplet.start(MyApplet.java:38)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

MyClass line 187 is just:
MyClass2 obj = new MyClass2();

All other FileNotFoundException traces are identical, but missing other files.
Also, on this system, I have more than one release (academic and commercial version, for exemple) and a lot of the jars that are being required are not in the academic version, but I can compile the other versions using the same code without having problems with it needing these jars.

I know is kind of a tough situation to give help, but I though that maybe someone has been in a similar situation and could give me a hint.

Also, is there any chance that the fact that I have some method like:

```
public void myMethod() {
 ClassInOneOfTheJars c = new ClassInOneOfTheJars();
}
```

but never could this method could make the VM try to fetch the jar that contains ClassInOneOfTheJars? (As far as I've read, it seems like the answer would be 'no').

Comment: If you're getting ClassNotFoundExceptions is because evidently you are indeed using the classes in question. If you believe you do not need them, then why is you code instantiating them? I guess without looking at the code only you could answer that.

Comment: Without more details and a stack trace it's going to be impossible for anyone to help.

Comment: Its actually a FileNotFoundException (if I put the files in there, everything runs fine, but I shouldn't need these files, that's the problem).
Added an exemple stack trace.

Comment: The hint is at `at my.package.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:187)`. Go to `MyClass.java` line `187`, you should find it staring at your face. Do you really need that line, try commenting it and see what happen.

Comment: Is there code that explicitly tries to load `jess.jar`? Because this seems more like that the URL to this `.jar` is on your application's classpath, and Java would access it eventually while looking for *any* class not loaded yet. Maybe you just need to remove that URL from the classpath.

Comment: @Rosdi, like I said on the post, line 187 is just: MyClass2 obj = new MyClass2(); which is a class that is not on these jars.

Comment: @Álvaro, yes.. have you tried commenting it?

Comment: @Rosdi yes, the errors go away as expected, still not understanding why the errors are there when instantiating this class, I asked the question.

Comment: @millimoose that was exactly the problem, thanks for the help.
If you want, add a answer and I will accept that.
But the jars on the classpath are supposed to be loaded on startup, right? Any ideas why the errors appeared only when I instantiated MyClass2 then?

Comment: @Álvaro Done, with an explanation of how your errors might have occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, what happened is that only when trying to load `MyClass2` did the JVM try and access `less.jar` when searching the classpath. My guess is that just how classes are only loaded when they're needed the first time, so are `.jar`s / other classpath entries only first accessed when a class is not found in the previous ones.

One way to explain the behaviour you see is that your classpath contains these `.jar`s in the following order:

1. `a.jar` (local)
2. `less.jar` (remote)
3. `b.jar` (local)

Where `MyClass` is in `a.jar`; and `MyClass2` is in `b.jar`. The classloader tries to load `MyClass`, opens `a.jar`, finds it there and loads it, and starts running the constructor. The constructor needs `MyClass2`, so the classloader opens `a.jar`, doesn't find the class there, and moves on to the next classpath entry. This is `less.jar`, which is inaccessible, and you get the crash. When you removed the inaccessible `.jar` from the classpath, the classloader can move on to `b.jar` and finds `MyClass2` there.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. That's why I was getting all the FileNotFoundExceptions at the same time.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `MyClass2` uses something in `less.jar`, hence causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the line

```
at my.package.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:187)
```

This means an object of type `MyClass` is being initialized. I'll bet line 187 is an inlined constructor call, a line inside the constructor body, or else a default field value initialization.

The initialization is ultimately trying to load something in `jess.jar`, and that's what's causing the error.